# Indirectly import R libraries from Github to R

Tags: r, github

I have just built a function and planned to put it into Github. The problem is that my function uses a lot of other R packages (e.g., dplyr, tidyverse,...), leading to when people clone my package from Github to R using `remotes::install_github`, they will have to additionally install those packages (e.g., dplyr, tidyverse,...). I wish when they install my package, they can use my package immediately. In other words, is any way to let they be able to simultaneously install all those packages when installing my R package.

My potential solution is that I will create a separate RData file whose role is to install and call those R libraries. Does it work?

Comment: Are you looking to create a package (i.e. functions and their dependencies)? If so there are loads of resources available to you, e.g. see https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486488-Developing-Packages-with-RStudio

Comment: No sir. I grasp the way to create a function and put it to my Github well. The problem is that my function uses a lot of other R packages (e.g., dplyr, tidyverse,...), leading to when people clone my package from Github to R using install_github, they will have to additionally install those packages (e.g., dplyr, tidyverse,...). I wish when they install my package, they can use my package immediately

Comment: One way to avoid requiring those external dependencies is to use base-r syntax equivalents for tidyverse functions e.g. https://tavareshugo.github.io/data_carpentry_extras/base-r_tidyverse_equivalents/base-r_tidyverse_equivalents.html

Comment: The problem is I use nearly different fifteen packages to build my package :(

Comment: Then I don't think there's much you can do except include each dependency and the required version under `Imports:` in your DESCRIPTION file and hope that the user already has some/many of those packages already installed. I'm not sure why having to download/install packages is a problem though - every package I have ever used has multiple dependencies and it's not a problem for me... Maybe other StackOverflow users have other ideas?

Comment: Add a `Remotes` field to the DESCRIPTION file and add the relevant packages.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for {renv} https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html or {packrat} https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/